magento oauth is not working with apache airflow
I want to use Apache airflow for automation tasks related to Magento, so I'm trying to create an order sync.
https://github.com/sivajik34/magento-airflow
below oauth authentication is not working.
import urllib.parse

import hmac

import hashlib

import base64

import time

import uuid

from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException



class MagentoHook(BaseHook):



    def __init__(self, magento_conn_id='magento', *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.magento_conn_id = magento_conn_id

        self.connection = self.get_connection(self.magento_conn_id)

        self._configure_oauth()



    def _configure_oauth(self):

        """Configure OAuth authentication for Magento API"""

        conn = self.get_connection(self.magento_conn_id)

        self.consumer_key = conn.extra_dejson.get('consumer_key')

        self.consumer_secret = conn.extra_dejson.get('consumer_secret')

        self.access_token = conn.extra_dejson.get('access_token')

        self.access_token_secret = conn.extra_dejson.get('access_token_secret')



        if not all([self.consumer_key, self.consumer_secret, self.access_token, self.access_token_secret]):

            raise AirflowException("Magento OAuth credentials are not set properly in Airflow connection")



    def _generate_oauth_parameters(self, url, method, data=None):

        """Generate OAuth parameters for the request"""

        oauth_nonce = str(uuid.uuid4())

        oauth_timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

        oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256'

        oauth_version = '1.0'



        # Parse the URL to separate the query parameters

        parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)

        query_params = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(parsed_url.query)



        # Prepare OAuth parameters

        oauth_params = {

            'oauth_consumer_key': self.consumer_key,

            'oauth_nonce': oauth_nonce,

            'oauth_signature_method': oauth_signature_method,

            'oauth_timestamp': oauth_timestamp,

            'oauth_token': self.access_token,

            'oauth_version': oauth_version

        }



        # Include data parameters if present

        if data:

            query_params.extend(data.items())



        # Combine OAuth and query/data parameters, and sort them

        all_params = oauth_params.copy()

        all_params.update(query_params)

        sorted_params = sorted(all_params.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])



        # Encode and create the parameter string

        param_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted_params, safe='')



        # Construct the base string

        base_string = f"{method.upper()}&{urllib.parse.quote(parsed_url.scheme + '://' + parsed_url.netloc + parsed_url.path, safe='')}&{urllib.parse.quote(param_str, safe='')}"



        # Create the signing key

        signing_key = f"{urllib.parse.quote(self.consumer_secret, safe='')}&{urllib.parse.quote(self.access_token_secret, safe='')}"



        # Generate the OAuth signature

        oauth_signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(signing_key.encode(), base_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()



        # Add the signature to OAuth parameters

        oauth_params['oauth_signature'] = oauth_signature



        # Construct the Authorization header

        auth_header = 'OAuth ' + ', '.join([f'{urllib.parse.quote(k)}="{urllib.parse.quote(v)}"' for k, v in oauth_params.items()])        

        return auth_header



    def get_request(self, endpoint, method='GET', data=None):

        """Perform an API request to Magento"""

        url = f"https://{self.connection.host}/rest/default/V1/{endpoint}"

        headers = {

            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

            'Authorization': self._generate_oauth_parameters(url, method, data)

        }



        try:

            if method.upper() == 'GET':

                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)  # Use GET method

            else:

                response = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)  # Use method provided



            response.raise_for_status()  # Will raise an error for bad responses



        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:

            error_details = None

            try:

                # Attempt to parse and log the error response

                error_details = response.json() if response.content else {}

                self.log.error(f"Error details: {error_details}")

            except ValueError:

                # Failed to parse JSON response

                pass



            raise AirflowException(

                f"Request failed: {http_err}. Error details: {error_details}"

            )



        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

            raise AirflowException(f"Request failed: {str(e)}")



        return response.json()



    def get_orders(self, search_criteria=None):

        """

        Fetch orders from Magento.



        :param search_criteria: Dictionary containing search criteria to filter orders

        :return: List of orders

        """

        endpoint = "orders"



        if search_criteria:

            # Convert search criteria dictionary to URL parameters

            query_string = urlencode(search_criteria, doseq=True)

            endpoint = f"{endpoint}?{query_string}"



        self.log.info(f"Requesting orders from Magento: {endpoint}")

        return self.get_request(endpoint)

